# How can I modify the header of RSS feed items?

Tags: hooks, author, feed, headers

Specifically I would like to change the value of `<dc:creator>` in the feed items. In order to display the site name instead of the post author.

I'm able to hook into `the_title_rss` , `the_excerpt_rss` and `the_content_feed`, but can't find how to change the header elements of a feed item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this value comes from the template `tag the_author()`.
You can also filter this.
But it is important, that you check, that the filter only work on the feeds; see the follow example at the check for `is_feed()`.
After this i change the autor name only, if the string has the value 'name_xyz'; here is the point that you change your data from your requirements.

I write from scratch, don't tested!

```
add_filter( 'the_author', 'fb_change_fead_creator', 10 );
function fb_change_fead_creator( $text ) {

    if ( ! is_feed() )
        return;

    if ( 'name_xyz' == $text )  
        $text = 'my new name';

    return $text;
}
```

Best

Comment: Great, that works! I guess the same logic can be applied if you want to change the date, hook into `the_date`

Comment: Yes, same logic